# SQL Upload syntax

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm struggling to get this UPDATE query to work.

I've tried:

```
"UPDATE status SET status (status, color) VALUES (@0, @1) WHERE id=@2"
"UPDATE status SET status (status, color) VALUES (@0, @1) WHERE (id) VALUES(@2)"
```

However when I do Insert, it works:

```
"INSERT INTO status (id, status, color) VALUES (@0, @1, @2)"
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

```
string sqlCommand = "UPDATE status SET status (status, color) VALUES (@0, @1) WHERE (id) VALUES(@2 )";
                    List<string> sqlCommandArgs = new List<string>(new string[] { 
                        (statusTextBox.Text.First().ToString().ToUpper() + statusTextBox.Text.Substring(1)),
                        color,
                        ((Status)(statusListBox.SelectedItem)).statusID.ToString()
                    });
                    SqlLoader.insertRowSqlDatabase(sqlCommand, sqlCommandArgs);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fields to be updated are assignments separated by commas.

```
UPDATE status SET status = @0, color = @1 WHERE id=@2
```

Read more: [Update statement in SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/syntax/update-stmt.html)

Comment: Dang, I was really hoping to stay within the format above. Thanks for the link !

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE status SET
[status] = @0,
[color] = @1
WHERE id = @2
```